# Insert record to mysql from JSON

Tags: php, mysql, json

I tried to insert a record onto MySQL DB from JSON. I ried something like this:

```
// Check if the user is recorded on DB
$sql    = 'SELECT * FROM accounts WHERE email = :email AND password = :password';
$params = array('email' => $email, 'password' => $password);
$account   = $db->fetchOne($sql, $params);
if (!$account){

    //call api
    $url = 'http://example.com/index.php/auth?key=@13456&email={$email}&password={$password}';
    $json = file_get_contents($url);
    $decode = json_decode($json, true);

    foreach ($decode as $value) {
      foreach ($value as $key => $value) {
        echo $value;
      }
    }


    //insert account 
    $insertdata = $db->insert(
       'accounts',
        array(
            'email'             => $value['email'],
            'password'          => sha1($value['password'])

        )
    );        
}else{
    sendJsonError('We could not find your email.');
    return;
}
```

The json response itself is:

```
{"status":"success","email":"jhon@mail.com","password":"%4fksdhj*"}
```

If on the api call I write the email dan password value directly, the record insert to DB, but when I create it dynamically like the API call above it won't record on the system.

Can you guys advise how to do it?

Comment: Are the curly brackets `{` and `}` round the parameter values in the URL necessary?

Comment: no, if call the api with the value directly without bracket

Comment: No I mean like `$url = 'http://example.com/index.php/auth?&key=@13456&email=$email&password=$password';` Or actually, try `$url = 'http://example.com/index.php/auth?&key=@13456&email='.$email.'&password='.$password;` .

Comment: I already call the api same like your mentioned but no luck :(. Is only works if i put the value directly on API call, something like:
$url = 'http://example.com/index.php/auth?key=@13456&email=willy@mail.com&password=123456A';

Comment: The other potential issue with this is url-encoding. I think passing the username and password (which could contain characters considered invalid in a URL) on the querystring is a bad idea. Also it's not very secure if the URL called gets logged in server access logs etc. This remote API ought to accept the values inside the request body in a POST request, really.

Comment: P.S. When you say "no luck", what do you mean? What exact response do you get from the server in that case?

Comment: Also, what is the purpose of this API? Right now, you retrieve a record from the database which matches an email and password combo (presumably, this is taken from user input??). If you find a matching, you send this data to an API and get back a response also containing an email and password - are they the same ones, or not? Then (without checking if the API call is successful) you try to insert a brand new record into the same database table containing the email and a hashed version of the password. I cannot understand what this is meant to achieve?

Comment: Why do you say you are trying to `INSERT`, when your query says `SELECT` ?

Comment: @Mawg the second query is an insert. But see my last comment. This whole process does not appear to make much sense.

Comment: if i put the value directly on API call, something like:
$url = 'http://example.com/index.php/auth?key=@13456&email=willy@mail.com&password=123456A'; than the willy@mail.com and password 123456A inserted to DB.

Comment: "password 123456A"...what happened to the %27? Anyway please answer my other questions. Your whole code does not really make sense in terms of what it's trying to do.

Comment: @Mawg I tried to check it first on the DB if user exist no need to call the API but if not exist than check on the API and insert

Comment: if you're sha1-ing your passwords into the database (as per your insert query), your initial select query will not match anything - you'd have to sha1- the user's input first.

Comment: "sendJsonError('We could not find your email.');" makes no sense either - you're sending this when you _did_ find the email (and password). The message says the opposite.

Comment: Hi @ADyson I following your url call: $url = 'http://example.com/index.php/auth?&key=@13456&email='.$email.'&password='.$password; and than i decode with echo, so after echo next step is insert to DB. and it's works like charm. Can you put it on answer I will checked it. Big Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe your code is not reading the parameter values correctly, because your string is in single quotes (`'`). PHP only interpolates the variables when the string is within double quotes (`"`).

So you can either

a) write it like this using concatenation:

```
$url = 'http://example.com/index.php/auth?&key=@13456&email='.$email.'&password='.$password;
```

b) put it in double-quotes:

```
$url = "http://example.com/index.php/auth?key=@13456&email=$email&password=$password";
```

(The curly braces are optional unless you're interpolating a more complex expression than just a single variable.)

P.S. A couple of other extra points:

You should consider the potential for problems due to URL-encoding of special characters within the password (leading to potential mis-interpretation at the remote server). Really this should be done as a POST request with the values within the request body, instead of the querystring. This will also prevent security leaks due to webservers etc logging URLs which are visited.

You should also really check that the HTTP request was definitely successful before assuming you can process the response.